# PHP script generating too many MySQL connections

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have a script that check for several twitch channels every 5 minutes, so I can have a list of the streams I want on my website that are currently live.

The problem is, this script is generating a lot of mysql_connections and i'm getting some errors about max connections limit.

As far as I know, if I open a connection to mysql and run several queries on my script, it's still one connection right?

My script goes like this:

1) connect to the database

2) check the current time

3) mysql query that updates a table with site tasks, inserting current time

4) mysql query on the streamers list table

5) for every record, it gets a xml on twitch with the data and saves to the database if it's online or not, how many viewers, etc

6) mysql_close

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? At first I thought it was another GoDaddy bug, but since this only happens when I'm running this task, I didn't bother to talk to them before check this.

Comment: will be better if you could post some of your code

Comment: getting the too many connections error means most likely, you didn't do mysql_close enough :P what do you mean with every 5 min.? that's impossible with pure php. if you do one mysql_connect, you should do one mysql_close. in between, you're right, it's one connection for all queries you do.

Comment: Since I have a lot of pageviews, I have a script that check a table with some tasks and if need, it runs the script to get streams on twitch.

$query = mysql_query("select * from site_tasks_helper");
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $streams_last_verified = $rs["streams_last_verified"];
    if (time() > strtotime("+5 minutes", $streams_last_verified)) {

    exec("/web/cgi-bin/php5 -f /var/chroot/home/content/57/8793357/html/lib/update_streams.php > /dev/null  &", $arrOutput );
}

Comment: @Satya http://pastebin.com/uMsjWLdM

Answer (score 1):

Try persistent conections in php.ini, http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php
also since you will use persistant and the next script's instance might reuse this connection you might want to avoid **mysql_close**

Comment: If I understand correctly, mysql_pconnect keeps the connection alive when the script ends, is that it? I'm using mysql_connect right now.

Comment: mysql_connect() is the right command to stablish a connection with/to mysql server, just make sure that you are NOT using the "new_link" parameter, though I think PHP is creating a new connection with every script instance.

If persistent connection wont solve your problem then you can try:

mysql_close($link);
$link = null;   // to clear this var and force close.

Comment: I'm connecting just once, on beggining of the script. The function is something like this:

function ConectToDB() {
    $conex_site = mysql_connect(server, user, password);
    mysql_select_db(database);
    return $MyConnection;
}

Comment: I just realized something... Apache is a **Multi-process web server** meaning that he will create another worker process for each script instance which of course will create another connection to the DB. Try using mysql_pconnect() or mysqli_connect(p:$host). Do you have access to the apache config file by any chance?

Comment: I don't, I'm using a shared account on GoDaddy. What's really weird is that, this script only run once every 5 minutes, so I don't really think is a matter on how many people are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include_once ('connectdb.php');` at the top of your script.
and `connectdb.php` should be something like you wrote at your comment.

connectdb.php

```
$conex_site = mysql_connect(server, user, password); mysql_select_db(database);
```

EDIT 1:

```
<?php

    $MyConnection = mysql_connect(server, user, password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(database) or die(mysql_error());
    return $MyConnection;//or return true;
}
?>
------------ mysql_connect.php -------------

------------ update_streams.php ------------
<?php
$con=include_once('mysql_connect.php');//or just include once('mysql_connect.php');
```

Comment: @PauloManrique how do you manage calling .php program every 5 seconds? with javascript `settimeout()`?please  put your code

Comment: I'm calling every 5 minutes, not every 5 seconds. I just have a function checking when was the last time it was checked before, if it was more than 5 minutes, then it calls the script.

http://pastebin.com/hu2q4Fyr

Comment: How to manage to call your function every 5 or x minutes? also where is you `mysql_connect()` at your code?

Comment: This part of the script runs on every page of the website, since I have a lot of visitors. My mysql_connect() is on this script: http://pastebin.com/uMsjWLdM

Comment: you `require_once` php connection file, but call main function for connection every time. I don't why you use this kind of calling. I edited my answer. see if it is useful

Comment: also why you use, `mysql_close()`, if you have one db connection, do not use it

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `my.cnf` configuration file. On CentOS, RedHat and similar distributions this is at `/etc/my.cnf`; other distros will store it elsewhere.

Under the `[mysqld]` section add the following setting:

```
max_connections = 200
```

Now when you restart MySQL the next time it will use this setting instead of the default.

`200` is a number that you are specifying that is more than the existing no. So assuming the current setting is 100 you can set a higher number.

Additionally, if you have root/admin access to MySQL then you can send the following command to increase the max connection on the fly till the server is restarted.

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

Note that increasing the number of connections that can be made will increase the potential amount of RAM required for MySQL to run. Increase the max_connections setting with caution!

Comment: I don't have access to my.cnf since is a shared hosting on GoDaddy. I'm pretty sure is not about the limit, max connections are 1000 and max user connections = 200